# How to assign names to a dataframe in Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

At every step shall I be introducing a new variable name or I can continue to use the same name. Kindly advise what's the best practice and why?

```
df1 = df.withColumn('last_insert_timestamp', lit(datetime.now())
df2 = df1.withColumn('process_date', lit(rundate)
```

Versus

```
df = df.withColumn('last_insert_timestamp', lit(datetime.now())
df = df.withColumn('process_date', lit(rundate)
```

Comment: Best practices questions and naming recommendation questions are both off-topic subjects here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

There is no best practice for that. It depends on what you want to do.

In Python, variables are just labels assigned to an object. So if you need your original DF object to be modified through your code then change the assignment to the newly generated DF.

Now, if you need to keep the first DF for other processing later in the code, then you may assign a new variable name.

You might find more explanations here: [Reassigning Variables in Python](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-variables-in-python-3#reassigning-variables)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
df = df.withColumn('last_insert_timestamp', lit(datetime.now()) \
       .withColumn('process_date', lit(rundate)
```